# Automatically delete most recent screenshot

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a method that will  and detect when a screenshot has been created and immediately delete it. I'm using FileObserver to observe the screenshot directory and flag when a new file is created in said directory. I don't know that the syntax is entirely correct, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
private void deleteMostRecentScreenshot() {
    /**
     * Set the path for the screenshot directory.
     */

    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "Screenshots";
    OLog.d(TAG, path);
    /**
     * Array of the files in our screenshot directory, sorted so that the oldest pictures are first.
     */

    final File[] screenshots = new File(path).listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(screenshots, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        }
    });
    /**
     * Watch for when a new file is created in our directory, ignoring "probes" created when the camera
     * is launched. If a new file is created, delete the last file in the array, which should be
     * the newest picture.
     */
    FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(path) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

            OLog.d(TAG, event + "" + path);
            if (event == FileObserver.CREATE && !path.equals(".probe")) {
                OLog.d(TAG, "File Created ["
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                        + "Screenshots"
                        + path
                        + "]");
                screenshots[screenshots.length - 1].delete();
            }
        }
    };
    fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Comment: "I'm using FileObserver to observe the screenshot directory" -- I would not assume that there is a consistent directory for this, across the thousands of Android device models. Beyond that, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare +1, every phone has a different directory to the screenshots folder. mine is - DCIM/Screenshots (Galaxy s6)

Comment: @CommonsWare This code is only going to be supported on the Nexus 6 and Nexus 5s, for both of these phones the screenshot directories are the same. I'm still fairly new to coding, I was unsure if there were any glaringly obvious mistakes in the above code. I had asked a few of the other programmers I work with if they saw anything out of place, looked at numerous other SO articles and still wasn't sure why it wasn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> I had asked a few of the other programmers I work with if they saw anything out of place, looked at numerous other SO articles and still wasn't sure why it wasn't working as intended.

It is unclear exactly what you are intending. Here are two oddities that I see:

1. Your `FileObserver` will randomly stop observing files, as it will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as `deleteMostRecentScreenshot()` returns. And, as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) points out, "If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object."
2. Your statement that "the last file in the array... should be the newest picture" is incorrect. At best, it will have been the most-recently-modified file as of the time when you called `listFiles()`. Changes that occur after `listFiles()` is called will not affect your `screenshots` array. Since your `FileObserver` is given the path to the file, you might consider just using that path.

Comment: I want to prevent the user from taking a screenshot at anytime. `FLAG_SECURE` isn't an option. So, my thought was that if I was able to delete the screenshot as soon as it was created, that would be just as good as it never being taken.

1. I came across that in the documentation, but was confused by the language. How would I "keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object"?

2. If the pictures were deleted as soon as they were created, wouldn't this mean the most recently modified file is the newest by default? 

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Evan: "I want to prevent the user from taking a screenshot at anytime" -- the user can install a third-party app that takes screenshots using the media projection APIs and stores them somewhere other than where you are looking. Moreover, your technique at best will work while your process is running, and the user can stop your process whenever the user wants.

Comment: @Evan: "How would I keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object?" -- well, at minimum, the object cannot be referenced solely by a local variable in a method. The closest thing you will have for something that works is to use a long-lived `Service` to manage the `FileObserver`, and even Android will get rid of that after a while.

Comment: @Evan: "wouldn't this mean the most recently modified file is the newest by default?" -- yes, but that is not what you are doing. Instead of files, think of numbers. You have an array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. You got that array by examining something else, but your array is a separate Java object than that "something else". The user does something which causes the "something else" to now have 6. Your algorithm deletes 5, because your array does not have a 6. You only populate the array once, and so it becomes out of date within nanoseconds.

Comment: And since the FileObserver is getting garbage collected, it wouldn't be updating that array?

Comment: @Evan: It is not updating the array because you have no code to update the array. You have code inside the `FileObserver` to *reference* the array, that's it.